# Querying data results a lock on the querying table

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

In the code below, when I call the method EntityADAO.findByGroupId(...), the table EntityA is locked until the transaction is complete.  I don't want this.  How can I avoid the table locking?  Thanks in advance.

```
My database is SQL SERVER 2012.  I am suing Hibernate 4.0.2.
```

Below is the code excerpt:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = EntityA)
    @NamedQueries ({
        @NamedQuery(name="EntityA.findByGroupId", query="SELECT p FROM EntityA p WHERE p.groupId= :groupId")})    
public class EntityA implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "EntityKey", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long entityKey;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "Version", nullable = false)
    private Long version = -1l;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "GroupId")
    private Integer groupId;
}

@Repository("EntityA")
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class EntityADAO  extends AbstractJpaDAO<EntityA> {

@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager em;

    public EntityADAO() {
        setClazz(EntityADAO.class);
    }

    **//A call to this method locks the table EntityA until the transaction is complete**
    public List<EntityA> findByGroupId(int groupId) {               
        TypedQuery<EntityA> query = em.createNamedQuery("EntityA.findByGroupId", EntityA.class);
        query.setParameter("groupId", groupId);
        return query.getResultList();       
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the result query? What is your transaction isolation level?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong SQL Server does not come with row versioning enabled by default, hence I think this is why you're seeing this behavior.

What I suspect is when you issue a select query, and before this query finishes you issue another update query, the update has to wait until the select is complete.

There are many approach to solve this problem, with one being [enabling the row versioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175095%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Other option include using the least restrictive isolation level.